# Need help on publishing xml report with the plugin parasoft findings in TeamCity

Tags: plugins, teamcity, parasoft

I added a build step for my project in teamcity which consists on using the plugin Parasoft Findings to publish an XML report of all the code violations. the problem is that teamcity is failing to parse XML report. It says there is an unexpected report format and to see log (which I couldn't find).

I already checked the report location pattern which is right. I don't use SOAtest but C++ test so I only put "Parasof analyzers 10.x" for the report type

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry but you did not provide any additional details regarding your question and it's hard to help you.
Please, provide:

- error message
- your configuration of build step and version of TeamCity and C++test
- command line used to start C++test ( if you are using variables,
  replace variables with real values used in your run)

By log I think, you should check your build step log, and provide us the right content.
You can find such logs on two different ways:

1. You can download it by clicking "Download full build log" on build
   log page (Recommended).
2. Try to find the raw output from the build agent by looking in the
   agents *logs* directory, for example in
   c:\TeamCity_dir_agent\logs\teamcity-build.log
   Following [article](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/viewing-build-agent-logs.html) from JetBrains' TeamCity manual might good point to start

Answer (score 0):

Edit:
Parasoft updated the plugin which fixed the issue:

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9949-parasoft-findings

I have the same issue. Error messages in build log:

```
Unexpected report format: <path-to>\report.xml. See log for details.
Failed to parse XML report
Failed to parse XML report
Step test results (Parasoft Findings) failed
```

teamcity-agent.log and teamcity-build.log are having no entries within this build step because there is no piece of code which would write that into during this error case.

Edit/Workaround:

In the report the node `<ExecutedTestsDetails>` must be below the node `<Exec>`. The node still has the right indendation but it is at the same level as `<Exec>`. The xsl of TeamCity Plugin works perfectly if you fix the report xml manually.

[image]

To make it work you can add the Build Feature "File Content Replacer" like that:

Regex: `(?s)(<ExecutedTestsDetails.*?<\/ExecutedTestsDetails>).*?(<Exec.*?>)`

Replace with: `$2 $1`

[image]